# Swift 3 - Create for loop UIButtons

Tags: for-loop, swift3, uibutton

**Hello guys, I create 14 buttons in for loop but each 7 buttons in one variable for example:**

```
for i in 0...6 {
    var button = UIButton()
    ...
    var button2 = UIButton()
    ...
}
```

**But I want create 14 buttons in one variable with for loop like in the picture:**

[image]

**In the picture I do it with two buttons in one for loop**

**And my sizes, xAxis and yAxis it must be :**

```
let buttonWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 7
var xAxis : CGFloat = 1
let yAxis : CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.height - (tileWidth * 2) - 100
let yAxis2 : CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.height - (tileWidth + 100)
```

**So how can I create 14 button with using for loop with same sizes and axises ? like this :**

```
for i in 0...13 {

    var button = UIButton()
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

```
    let emptySpace:CGFloat = 40 //how much you want (left + right)
    var xAxis:CGFloat = emptySpace/2
    let space:CGFloat = 2
    let buttonWidth = ((self.view.frame.size.width)-((space*7)+emptySpace)) / 7

    var yAxis : CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.height - (tileWidth * 2) - 100
    let yAxis2 : CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.height - (tileWidth + 100)
    for i in 1...14 {

        let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        xAxis = xAxis+buttonWidth+space
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        view.addSubview(button)


        if i%7 == 0 {
            xAxis = emptySpace/2
            yAxis = yAxis2+space
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you bro, but can I get space of right screen and left ?? @KarthikeyanBose

Comment: check the edited one. But giving value like 10, 20 or 40 won't suit for all device. Its almost like harcode try to give value dynamically

Comment: Thank you, you are great ! :) @KarthikeyanBose